# Drinking soda triggers tingling on a tiny spot on my upper back... but how?

Tags: physiology, neurophysiology, human-physiology

The title pretty much says it all.  Yes, I know it doesn't make sense. That's why I'm baffled.

For the past week or two, I've noticed that drinking soda seems to cause a tingling/stinging sensation on a very tiny spot on the skin of my upper-left back. It happens within a second or two after I swallow. This has been happening pretty consistently since I first noticed it. (I've noticed it at least a dozen times; I'm pretty sure I'm not hallucinating...) I think it also happened once or twice when I was drinking plain water, but not enough for me to be sure whether or not I actually felt it or if I was just imagining things...

I've been otherwise healthy and there's nothing particularly special about that spot on my back, so I'm pretty baffled at the moment. How/why could this possibly be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The skin is a very richly innervated organ, and minor strange sensory phenomena are not exceedingly uncommon.

The thing about sensory nerves is that they can misfire and you seem to feel something when there's nothing there. This actually happens all over our bodies *all the time* (mostly our brain blocks them out, like it blocks out background noises after a while): an itch for no reason whatsoever (no bug, no bite, no reason) is the most common manifestation of this phenomenon.

Sensory nerves start their journey out of the central nervous system as relatively large bundles coming off the spinal cord, and keep on branching becoming finer and finer as they reach the periphery.

[image]

since there's a lot of muscle under the skin, most of these sensory nerves have to come up through muscle.

[image]

Sometimes an inflamed bundle of muscle fibers (aka a "knot") will entrap a small branch of a sensory nerve, and the pressure on the nerve will cause it to "misfire", causing a sensory illusion, if you will. If this is the case (*if* it's in the exact same spot every time) and a slender nerve branch is being squeezed by a muscle knot in your back, you can do a little test on yourself: have someone run a fine sharp object (say the end of a toothpick) softly over an area starting away from the spot going through it. If the sensation changes right on that spot - going from sharp to dull, for example - and does so consistently, that's what's going on. If you have the person map the change of sensation with a pen, the spot will be about the size of a quarter or smaller.

If, however, the sensation is only associated with swallowing, and there's no change to light touch, I have no idea what's going on.

Anyone reading this should know, though, that strange neurological symptoms can be an early sign of MS.

Comment: +1 thanks for the answer. I suspect it's just associated with swallowing, but I'll try to have someone do what you wrote just to see what happens. I'll have to wait until I get more soda though, so I can figure out the exact spot again first...